# Finding a function that satisfies certain integral conditions

Tags: inequality, integral-inequality, weak-derivatives

I'm trying to find a function $u:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with compact support which has a weak first derivative and satisfies the following conditions:

$$
\int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^2} |\partial_x u|^{3/2} < \infty,
\qquad 
\int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^2} |\partial_y u|^{3/2} < \infty,
\qquad
\int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^2} |u|^2|\partial_x u| = \infty
$$

Can anyone provide me an example of such a function, or a proof that no such function exists?

For context, I'm investigating embeddings of different function spaces into others. So far, I know that it won't work with a function of the form $u(x,y)=x^k$ for any $k \in \mathbb{R}$ (brought to zero away from the origin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not exist any such function.

It is clear that $u$ belongs to the Sobolev space $W^{1,\frac{3}{2}}(\Omega)$ for some $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ as defined in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0294144903000611), since the definition does not assume any integrability on $u$. The paper states that there is an embedding:

$$
W^{1,p}(\Omega) \hookrightarrow L^q(\Omega)
$$

where $q=np/(n-p)$. In our case, we have $q = 2*1.5/(2-1.5) = 6$. Then we can use Hölder's inequality to get:

$$
\int \limits_{\Omega} |u|^2|\partial_x u|
\leq
\left\|
|u|^2|\partial_x u|
\right\|_1
\leq
\left\|
|u|^2
\right\|_3
\left\|
|\partial_x u|
\right\|_{3/2}
=
\left\|
u
\right\|_6
\left\|
\partial_x u
\right\|_{3/2}
$$

Then, since we have established that $u \in W^{1, \frac{3}{2}}(\Omega) \subset L^6(\Omega)$, we conclude that the product must be finite.